# click event does not get fired after rerendering the page

Tags: javascript, click

I'm working on an addressbook application. I'm stuck on this problem and I can't figure out what's happening. For some reason the contacts click event does not fire again, after the page has rerendered. The click eventhandler on the contacts is created in the modal.js page. I loop through all contacts and create an event handler on them.

```
// Show Modal
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

// Listen for click event on each card
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 1) {
  cards[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let modal = '';
    const contact = contacts[i];

    // Create template literal
    modal = `
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal">
          <button type="button" id="modal-close-btn" class="modal-close-btn"><strong>X</strong></button>
          <div class="modal-info-container">
             <img class="modal-img" src="${
      contact.image
      }" alt="profile picture">
              <h3 id="name" class="modal-name cap">${contact.name} ${
      contact.surname
      }</h3>
              <hr>
              <p class="modal-text"><a href="tel:${contact.phone}">${
      contact.phone
      }</a></p>
              <p class="modal-text">${contact.address}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;


// Create Overlay
createOverlay(modal);

// Close Modal
closeModal();
```

});
}

For example if you click on a contact, the modal for the contact opens. But when you click the delete button, and then try to open another modal, the click event does not fire off. The same with searches. If the pages gets rerendered because of a search, the click event on the contacts does not get fired off anymore. I don't get an error message in the console. Maybe someone has a clue what's going on.

https://github.com/acandael/addressbook

Comment: It's better to post minimal code rather than just explaining your problem and sending link to your whole project. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks for the advice, I added some code.